# Why is there no generic implementation of OrderedDictionary in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Why did Microsoft not provide generic implementation of OrderedDictionary?

There are a few custom implementations I've seen, including: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GenericOrderedDictionary.aspx

But why did Microsoft not include it in the base .net library? Surely they had a reason for not building a generic.... but what is it?

Prior to posting this message, I did see: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary

But that just confirms that it does not exist. Not **why** it does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: There's always `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the SortedDict docs, that is not what I want. I don't want any sorting done.  I just want an array that I can also access by key.  Anyway, I am really wondering why MS skipped this.  (Subtle issues, etc.)

Comment: What's a typical use case for an ordered dictionary? I'm struggling to think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: @Carson anytime you have what is an array of data items that you also need quick random access to.  To simply store in a Dict loses the ordering information, and using an array requires your to maintain your own index.

Comment: yeah, I understand what it does - I'm just struggling to think of an example of a situation where you would use it. What sort of situations have you used an OrderedDictionary in?

Comment: Ask Eric Lippert to read and answer your question. He's usually very agreeable to helping out with this type of question. I think you can contact him via his blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/

Comment: @nonot1, this is a remark on your comment. If you have implicit order, that that order could be your key in the dictionary. to get random access you could use Linq.

Comment: I understand if you type their names three times in a row, either Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet will appear and answer your .NET question :-)

Answer (score 21):

The `OrderedDictionary` overloads the indexing operation so that indexing with an integer `N` will get the item in position `N`, while indexing with an `Object` will retrieve the item coresponding to that object.  If one were to create an `OrderedDictionary<int, string>` called `myDict`, and added items (1,"George") and (0,"Fred") in that order, should `myDict[0]` return "George" or "Fred"?

Such an issue could have been resolved by imposing a class constraint on the key type.  On the other hand, much of the usefulness of generic collections stems from their ability to efficiently work with value types.  Imposing a class constraint on the key type would seem a little ugly.

If the class didn't have to be CLS compliant but merely had to work with vb.net, a sensible design might have been to used named indexed properties.  Thus, in the example above, `myDict.ByKey[0]` would have yielded "Fred", and `myDict.BySequence[0]` would have yielded "George".  Unfortunately, languages like C# do not support named indexed properties.  While one could have kludged something to allow use of the above syntax even without such properties, the unfortunate decision to wrap the fields of structures like `Point` and `Rectangle` means that for `myDict.ByKey[0] = "Wally"` to work, `myDict.ByKey` would have to return a new class object.  A struct would be more efficient, but compilers would reject what looked like a write to a read-only structure (notwithstanding that the property wouldn't modify the struct returned by `ByKey`, but instead modify the collection to which it holds a reference).

Personally, I think a dictionary-ish object that was specified as keeping track of the insertion order would be a nice thing to have; I'd also like to have a dictionary-ish object which could easily return the key associated with a particular key (so that, e.g. if one has a case-insensitive dictionary and has added a record with a key of "GEORGE", one could ask the dictionary what key is associated with "George" without having to search through all the `KeyValuePair` objects returned in an enumeration.

Comment: Easily resolved by either a) choosing a behavior and clearly documenting (and never changing) it, b) adding a separate method that retrieves by index, or even c) making "int" an illegal key type. As long as the order does not change when retrieving by int, we don't care HOW it works. #sigh What I'm saying is ... it's not actually a hard problem.

Comment: @tekHedd: The only way to make `int` an illegal key type would be to add a class constraint, which is a possibility I'd mentioned.  Otherwise, the problem is that while VB.NET allows classes to have multiple indexed properties, C# doesn't.

Answer (score 19):

In *C# 4.0 In A Nutshell* I read this:

1. An `OrderedDictionary` is a combination of a `HashTable` and `ArrayList`
2. There is no generic `ArrayList`
3. "The nongeneric `ArrayList` class is used mainly for backward compatibility with Framework 1.x..."
4. "An `ArrayList` is functionally similiar to `List<object>`"
5. "Reflection is easier with a nongeneric `ArrayList` than a `List<object>`"

**Conclusion?**

No generic `OrderedDictionary` because it's underlying construct is a (unofficially) depreciated class that has no generic version itself.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. A generic OrderedDictionary could obviously be build on a generic Dictionary and a generic List.

Comment: One precept of class use is if the UI doesn't change who cares about implementation?  Well, the language design / compiler team, let's say, [might prefer the generic inheriting its non-generic counterpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes). My spidey sense boggles. For starters: Is differing (immediate) ancestors a land mine *somewhere* in the evolutionary path for  `OrderedDictionary` covariance and contra variance?

Answer (score 6):

Because maintaining order prevents the O(1) lookup that IDictionary implies unless you wrap two collections (one for order, one for lookup), which makes add/remove less performant and increases memory usage. Or you could have slower lookup in exchance for less memory usage.

My guess is that there was no 'clearly better' choice here, so it didn't go into the standard library. Especially around 2.0, C# was still learning from Java's mistakes. I wouldn't be surprised if Java's 'everything and the kitchen sink' approach to collections in their standard library was viewed as something to avoid as well.

Comment: Having slower look-up in exchange for less memory just effectively makes the `OrderedDictionary` a `List`. I'd imagine that anyone with a legitimate use case for an `OrderedDictionary` is using it specifically because they need a collection class that has O(1) lookup but also remembers insertion order, in which case using additional memory is unavoidable and thus acceptable.